# Unabe to change git editor

Tags: windows, git, git-config

I am trying to set the editor as the standard Notepad or even the Vim. However Git keeps showing me this message when I run `git commit`:

```
> hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... error: cannot spawn
> notepad++.exe: No such file or directory
```

I uninstalled the current git version I had installed and installed the new version **Git-2.36.1-64-bit** however the error persists (I already did it for the second time: this time choosing Vim instead of Notepad, with no success... always the same notepad++ error message shown).

I tried to find any old git config files that may have notepad++ setted up but I didn't find any. At %userprofile% folder there is the file with no editor setted. At the installation folder, under /etc also there is no editor setted. I already reboot the computer (even between instalations) but always got the same message.

This may come from an old installation that used to had notepad++ as default editor, but I re-installed it again twice choosing different editors and nothing changes.

Running `git config --list` brings no core.editor setting.

I also already ran the command `git config core.editor` with the correct path of the notepad.exe and nothing happens (even with the --global option).

I also checked under the "Program Data" folder, but the git config file there also doesn't have any editor setted.

I ran out of options, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Git will run the first setting it finds from: `$GIT_EDITOR`, `core.editor`, `$VISUAL`, `$EDITOR`, or compiled-in-default. If setting `core.editor` did not override things it must be using `$GIT_EDITOR`. (Note that several Git commands have yet another environment variable in front of `$GIT_EDITOR`: in particular `git rebase -i` uses `$GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` if set, or `sequence.editor` if not, and then falling back to this same procession of settings.)

Comment: @torek Thank you. I didn't know about those uses of env variables. That solved the matter. If you like, you can answer the question. I will accept as the answer.

Comment: So something had set `GIT_EDITOR`? What was that something?

Comment: @torek "notepad++.exe" was stored as the value of the environment variable GIT_EDITOR. I deleted the variable and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your particular case the culprit here was that something (not sure what the "something" was / is) had set `GIT_EDITOR` in your environment.  Using whatever command you need to unset the variable solved the problem.

Note that when Git goes to fire up an editor, it generally uses the *first value* from the following sequence of items, where `$` indicates an environment variable and the lack of a dollar sign indicates a `git config --get` setting (`git config --get` can both get the setting *and* report whether it exists, and Git uses the latter internally):

- `$GIT_EDITOR`
- `core.editor`
- `$VISUAL`
- `$EDITOR`

If none of these succeed, Git falls back on the compiled-in-default.

(When using `git rebase`, Git adds `$GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` and `sequence.editor` in to the front of the list before invoking any editor on the series of `pick` and other commands in the interactive rebase command sheet.  This means you can write a script that uses interactive rebase, but doesn't open the regular editor on the `pick` command-sheet, yet still opens the regular Git editor on any to-be-edited commits.)

The command-line invocation:

```
git var GIT_EDITOR
```

will obtain and print out the name of the editor Git is programmed to use.  In my case that's `vim` so `git var GIT_EDITOR` prints `vim`, but the command-line sequence:

```
(export GIT_EDITOR=example; git var GIT_EDITOR)
```

prints `example` instead since my shell set the environment variable `GIT_EDITOR` temporarily for the duration of that command.